# Does the <img> tag have an "onsuccess" attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, image

Does the `<img>` tag have an `"onsuccess"` attribute? Like `"onerror"`.

I am loading an image. I bind an event with JQuery, which changes image `onerror`.
i want to show an alert `"ONERROR Image loaded successfuly"` if `onerror image` successfully loaded. Otherwise it will show alert `"ONERROR image not found"`.

**EDIT:**
onload shows alert after loading image. but didn't tells us that `"your real image is loaded"` or `"browser's default error image is loaded"`. check here...

```
http://jsfiddle.net/extremerose71/cHuu6/6/
```

Comment: Are you looking for '`onload`'?

Comment: @Engineer: onload shows alert on load. but didn't tells us that "your real image is loaded" or "browser's default error image is loaded".

Comment: If "browser's default error image is loaded", then `"onerror"` will be called, if "your real image is loaded",then `"onload"` will be called.

Comment: @Engineer: it think it is not working as i want.. http://jsfiddle.net/extremerose71/cHuu6/5/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wrote something like:

```
<img id="im3" src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/j_f11bbae8.png" />​
```

And also wrote:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $("#im3").load( function (){
      alert('load');
   }).error( function (){
      alert('error');
   });
});
```

(as in `jsfiddle` `onLoad` is corresponded to `$(window).load`) , you will never get any `alert`, because `$(window).load` will be called after all resources is already loaded.

But if you would remove `src` from `img`:

```
<img id="im3"/>​
```

And then add this

```
$("#im3").attr('src','http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/j_f11bbae8.png' )​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
```

line after the `load` and `error` listeners , you will see an `alert`.

So the main problem was , that you were adding listeners after the image has already loaded or failed to load.

Comment: your research on jsfidle's working is really very appreciative.. but you are using `.load` for calling a function.. i think it is wrong.. because `.load` is used for loading data from server.. like AJAX...

Comment: And what data loads `$(window).load` ?!!  You are not enough aware of `jquery`.  For `img`s `load` is listener for `onload` event, as `error` is listener of `onerror` event.

Comment: I am talking about $("#im3").load( function (){
      alert('load');
   });

Comment: change your code to `$("#im3").bind('load', function (){
      alert('load');
}).error(function (){
      alert('error');
});` .. i want to accept your answer...

Comment: I have not used concatenated listeners only for demonstration purposes. No problem, I will concatenate them.

Comment: i am not just concatenated the listeners.. i am using .bind('load', ...) instead of .load(...) . And now it is working...

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use

```
function loadImage()
{
    alert("Image is loaded");
}
function errorImage()
{
    alert("Image not loaded");
}
<img src="someImg.png" onload="loadImage()" onerror="errorImage()" />
```

Reference: [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp) and [onerror](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onerror.asp).

> On successful image load onload event handler(loadImage function) will fire and if image is not loaded
>   then onerror event handler(errorImage function) will fire.

Comment: I use a kind of js themplate. onLoad worked for me:
<img src='/{image}' style='width:0px' onLoad='this.style.width="100px";' />

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do that, read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp).
You can use:

- onload
- onerror
- onabort

And all these three events are supported in all major browsers.

You can find these three events also on [MDN DOM event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference).

Comment: The community here don't like w3schools! There are some things that are not exactly like that. Refer to MDN or the real source - w3.

Comment: You are free to don't like w3schools, sometimes I can be agree too, but in this situation those three events works. I check them with safari and firefox too.

Comment: However I try to add also a MDN link.

Answer (score 1):

You can do  this using `onerror` and `onload` event handlers

```
var im = document.getElementById('imageid');
im.onload = function() {
   //handler
};

im.onerror = function() {
   //handler
};
```